# Frames are not identified when the browser user interface is not available (tests are run as services)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, frames

Scenario :
Integrating the selenium maven tests with Jenkins/Teamcity in order to schedule these tests once in a week.
The tests are for automating a website which contains many frames and subframes. So in order to identify an element every time i need to switch among frames.

Code snippet :

```
String Username = s.getCell(0,row).getContents();
String Password = s.getCell(1,row).getContents();
Login(Username,Password);
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Problem:
When the tests are run through command line or eclipse, they pass.
Problem occurs when the tests are run through Jenkins/Teamcity.
The reason might be that these two tools (Jenkins/Teamcity) do not perform tests on real browsers. Instead the tests are run from backend. Hence, the frames are not identified and exception is thrown.
Note : Even after putting wait condition before switching to frame exception is thrown.

Expected output :
Frames should be identified and switched successfully.

Actual output :

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Windows\TEMP\scoped_dir2716_17285}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=44.0.2403.157, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 5f43812bb3037e1d67f35126d19bc50d
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:869)
    at testproject.Browser.ExportTestCase(Browser.java:120)
    at testproject.testclass.Login(testclass.java:16)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  testclass.Login:16->Browser.ExportTestCase:120 » NoSuchFrame no such frame
  (...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\svn_workspace\TestlinkBackup\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 minutes 22 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 01 10:43:51 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/234M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\svn_workspace\TestlinkBackup\pom.xml to TestlinkBackup/TestlinkBackup/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TestlinkBackup-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Please provide solution to this.

Comment: Do you only have one frame in your page. if you want to switch to you frame you can put id and xpath also instead of index of frame. try with it

Comment: I have tried with xpath, id and cssselector but same issue there. The webpage contains 2 frames and some subframes withing these two frames. This code runs perfectly if run through command prompt or eclipse. It fails only when run through Jenkins/Teamcity.